# print string between two patterns but the first pattern is a range

Tags: date, sed

I have a file containing dates in the format `mmddyyyy`.

The file cotents are as below:

```
05192014
10212014
10222014
11232014
12242014
```

Now I wanted to print dates which have month 10 or 11 and year 2014, or it can also be dates between months ranging from 01 to 11.

for a single month and year this command is working fine:

```
cat filename | sed -n '/10/,/2014/p'
```

The above command prints:

```
10212014
10222014
```

All Good!

But if i wanted dates having month either 10 or 11 I did as below:

```
cat filename | sed -n '/1[0-1]/,/2014/p'
```

But the above command prints all the dates. Is there any way out. So that I can put a range in my first pattern.

Also, I should be able to get dates when I specify months in range for example:

print all dates with month greater than equal 01 and less than equal 11 and year 2014.

Then the output should be:

```
05192014
10212014
10222014
11232014
```

Comment: explain this `it can also be dates between months ranging from 01 to 11.`

Comment: ranging from 01 to 11 regarding to above data it should print 
05192014
10212014
10222014
11232014

Comment: kickoff that naughty element :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
$ sed -n '/^1[01].*2014$/p' file
10212014
10222014
11232014
```

`^1[01].*2014$` means: strings starting with `1` followed by either `0` or `1`, then a bunch of strings that end with `2014`.

If you want to just check dates on the format `MMDDYYYY`, then instead of `^1[01].*2014$/` you can just use `^1[01]..2014$`. Using `^` and `$` you avoid matching lines like `hello11112014bye` and so on.

Also, note there is no need to `cat ... | sed`. `sed ... file` is enough.

---

Note your current command is not doing what you expect: `sed -n '/10/,/2014/p' file` prints all the files from the one containing `10` to the one containing `2014`, so anything in between will appear. See:

```
$ cat a
05192014
10212014
asdfad
10222014
11232014
12242014
$ sed -n '/10/,/2014/p' a
10212014
asdfad
10222014
```

---

> Also, I should be able to get dates when I specify months in range for
>   example: print all dates with month greater than equal 01 and less
>   than equal 11 and year 2014.

```
$ sed -rn '/^(0[1-9]|1[01]).*2014$/p' file
05192014
10212014
10222014
11232014
```

Comment: working perfectly great..thankyou...thanks very much for also correcting me. can't get better explaination than this.

Comment: how to get dates between months ranging from 01 to 11 the output should be 05192014 10212014 10222014 11232014

Comment: @mSatyam update your question with proper input and output. In comments it is not clear.

Comment: @mSatyam see update. Note you should ask a different question instead of keeping adding conditions.

Comment: I got it, is this correct way:
sed -n '/^1[0-1]\|^0[1-9].*2014$/p' filename

Comment: @mSatyam yes, and if you use `sed -r` you can get rid of the `\` in `\|`.

Comment: @ fedorqui Note you should ask a different question instead of keeping adding conditions. I had asked this before I think you might not have read carefully that time.

Comment: @mSatyam Yep, now I notice it was already there. As you accepted the answer I thought you were done. It seems to me that now it really is.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n /1[01]..2014/p file
```

Output:

```
10212014
10222014
11232014
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '1[01]..2014' filename
```

will produce the output as

```
10212014
10222014
11232014
```

Answer (score 1):

> it can also be dates between months ranging from 01 to 11

```
$ grep -E '^(0[1-9]|1[01])..2014$' file
05192014
10212014
10222014
11232014
```